# Eloquent JavaScript - Having Issues With The Beginning of The Robot Project

Tags: javascript

In the Chapter 7 Robot Project, in Eloquent JavaScript, I am kind of having a hard time figuring the beginning portions of the robot project.

```
const roads = [
   "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
   "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
   "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
   "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
   "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
   "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
   "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"

];

function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);
  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
      console.log()
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }
  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }
  return graph;
}

const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);
console.log(roadGraph)
```

Here's what I don't understand. This line here is causing my issues because of the brackets around the from, to

```
for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-")))
```

When I run it in the eloquent javascript sandbox, it works, but when I try to run it in the cloud9 IDE, or Visual Studio Code, it gives me an array saying

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Why am I getting an unexpected token error in the cloud9 IDE or VS Code?

Also, I am not sure I get what is going on, so I will write what I think I understand from the early parts of this project; I would love for someone to give me some clarification on how this project works, if possible.

```
function buildGraph(edges){
}
```

The function buildGraph, Takes an array of destinations, makes each destination, a property of an object that we will create, and each of these properties will contain an array of destinations that can be accessed from that destination property.

```
function buildGraph(edges){
let graph = Object.create(null)

}
```

This creates an object with an empty prototype, called graph.

```
function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);

  //Here's Where The Confusion Starts
  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }
```

Create a function called addEdge that takes two parameters, which I believe will be destinations. But this portion here, kills me, I honestly don't get what is going on here.

```
   if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }
```

May someone help? This is my first question on stack overflow, so I apologize if my question wasn't asked 100% correct. But any assistance would be great.

Comment: Array items need to be separated by commas. Your code, which does not do that everywhere, is causing a syntax error.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: It is a typo, irrelevant to the posed questions. (But yes, OP, in the future please do copy-paste your code correctly :D )

Comment: sorry about that gentleman, my apologies. But even without typos, it's still causing a syntax error though.

Comment: The code works perfectly in VS Code. Maybe node needs to be updated for you. Older Node may not be supporting deconstruction(`[from, to]`) which is the source of your problem

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-")))
> ```

The deconstruction above is not available in older Node. It might be the case your IDE is using an old one (I don't have access to those IDEs, so this is just speculation). I've checked 5.6.0 and 10.9.0: the former doesn't support it, and the latter does.

However, I must admit I am a bit puzzled as to why, since apparently [spec prohibits `let` there](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iteration-statements) (although it is perfectly happy with `const`).

> ```
> if (graph[from] == null) {
>     graph[from] = [to];
>   } else {
>     graph[from].push(to);
>   }
> }
> ```

`graph` is a mapping between nodes and lists of connected destinations. At the start, given that it starts off as a blank object, `graph[from]` will be `undefined`; but JavaScript more or less ignores the difference between `null` and `undefined` when you use `==` (as opposed to its stricter brother `===`). So when an origin doesn't have any destinations yet in the graph, we'll just set that to a one-element list containing the destination.

On the other hand, if we have already set something there, then `graph[from]` will already contain a list that we don't want to overwrite, so we'll just append the destination to it using `.push`.

For example, the first three iterations will build connections from `Alice's House`. The first `to` is `Bob's House`. So `graph["Alice's House"]` is `undefined`, and we put `["Bob's House"]` there. In the next iteration, it's from `Alice's House` to `Cabin`; but now `graph["Alice's House"]` is not empty, so we append to it, resulting in `["Bob's House", "Cabin"]`. At the end of the run, we'll know that if we're at Alice's House, there's three possible places we can go (Bob's House, Cabin and Post Office).

Comment: I've tried updating Node in cloud9, and I was still getting the error. I am puzzled as well as to why this is not working on my end, but it is working on the author's environment, when I run it in the Book's sandbox. But thank you for taking the time out to answer, now I am going to process everything you wrote, and see if I can make sense of it, and come back to the post with any more questions! Sorry about the typo, my apologies.

Comment: It did not unfortunately.

Comment: Well you can always rewrite it... `for (let edge of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) { let [from, to] = edge; ...` or even the very primitive `... let from = edge[0]; let to = edge[1]; ...`.

Comment: I got the same syntax error for your first example, and got undefined for the second example. I typed exactly what you wrote. Looks like I have some figuring out to do. :( , Sometimes I wish the example in this book were a little bit easier, just a tad bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (graph[from] == null) {
    graph[from] = [to];
  } else {
    graph[from].push(to);
  }
}
```

The code above is building a graph of the village. It will store "to" all the places you can visit "from" any given place.

So It checks whether there is already any road added to this array or not. If not, it will initialise the array with the destination to the node's array. Similarly, if the array already have some destinations from the given array, it will append all other destinations to the array.

Hope it helps.

**Update:**

```
for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-")))
```

You can understand this with an example. The map function will return an array of array. e.g passing an array [a-b, b-c] will return a new array [[a, b], [b, c]]. Now in the for loop, you will iterate through each of these elements in this new array. In interation 1, following thing happens.

```
[from, to] = [a, b];
```

So 'from = a' (a here is a location in the village), and 'to = b' (b is another location in the village such that a and b are connected with the road. These values are then passed to the addEdge function to add them to the graph.

I hope my answer makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It makes sense a little bit, but do you mind also explaining how this works as well

for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-")))

Amadan explained it well, but I would love to hear your explanation about this, if you can. Nonetheless, thank you for your assistance

Comment: @RobertCastillo I've updated my answer with my further explanation. Please vote it up if you find my answer helpful.

Comment: I tried to vote both answers that I've received up, but I guess I don't have enough reputation yet for it to show :(, my apologies, but thanks for your help. I'll vote up once I get more rep.

Comment: it's perfectly fine. I'm also a newbie here. Also, it would be very easy for us to debug code and syntax errors if you could provide us a link to a shared online editor.

Comment: That sounds great, is there a chatroom where I can shared the link to the editor I am using? I don't want the link to be publicly available.

Comment: sorry I'm not aware of such a chatroom. Maybe you could replicate your error on a public site such a jsfiddle, stackblitz, or codepen.

Comment: @RobertCastillo somehow the page is not loading.

Comment: I guess we can do it this way. I just followed you on Github, so I will create a new 'issue' in your eloquent javascript repository, with a link that we can both access. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, we sure can.