# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 7 - where do the key names come from?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding what's happening in the opening bit of code in Eloquent Javascript's Chapter 7.

```
const roads = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House",   "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office",   "Bob's House-Town Hall",
  "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
  "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
  "Grete's House-Shop",          "Marketplace-Farm",
  "Marketplace-Post Office",     "Marketplace-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Town Hall",       "Shop-Town Hall"
];

  function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);
  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }
  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }
  return graph;
}

const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);
```

The following explanation, as provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156959/eloquent-javascript-having-issues-with-the-beginning-of-the-robot-project), makes sense in and of itself:

> For example, the first three iterations will build connections from
> Alice's House. The first to is Bob's House. So graph["Alice's House"]
> is undefined, and we put ["Bob's House"] there. In the next iteration,
> it's from Alice's House to Cabin; but now graph["Alice's House"] is
> not empty, so we append to it, resulting in ["Bob's House", "Cabin"].
> At the end of the run, we'll know that if we're at Alice's House,
> there's three possible places we can go (Bob's House, Cabin and Post
> Office).

I'm confident I understand the logic behind how the array is populated. But here's what I don't understand:

1. If the value array represents destinations, and the key represents the
   origin, why are we pushing to an array called 'from'? Is that just a bad choice of naming or am I missing something? It's certainly causing confusion for me.
2. If the array is a value of the object's key-value pairs, how are the keys
   getting their names? I can't work out where in the process this
   occurs, though when I console.log the object it clearly has keys.
3. On the second iteration, how does the function know to look to create a new key-value pair? It seems it would just keep appending to the 'from' array....

Could someone please perhaps walk me through the first couple of iterations in more detail? I've spent a great deal of time trying to work this out but feel like I've reached a dead end.

Comment: 1. There is no array named from. 2. From from. 3. It _doesn't_ create a new pair, it pushes to the existing array if one is present. Use a debugger (in your IDE or e.g. https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit), or just add some console.logs.

Comment: Use the console `function addEdge(from, to) { console.log(from, to, graph[from]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet the flow steps are printed out. See the comments in the snippet for some explanation.

To play around with this code I've created a [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-utvh4v?file=index.js).

```js
const log = Log();

const roads = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
];
const connections = buildGraph(roads);
log(` `, `**Result**`, JSON.stringify(connections, null, 2));

function buildGraph(edges) {
  const graph = {};
  /*
    [from] and [to] are strings sent from the (for) loop
    if [graph] contains a key [from], its value is an array, 
    so [to] is concatted to it. Otherwise graph[from]'s value 
    will be a new array, with first value [to] 
    In other words: [from] is always the key (a string), added if
    non existent in [graph], or supplemented with the
    value of [to]
  */
  const addEdge = (from, to) => {
    const exists = from in graph;
    log(`<code>graph['${from}']</code> exists?${ exists 
      ? ` yep.`
      : ` nope. (graph['${from}'] will be added with ["${to}"] as value.`}`);
    graph[from] = graph[from] ? graph[from].concat([to]) : [to];
    log(`  <code>graph['${from}']</code> value now ${JSON.stringify(graph[from])}`);
  }

  // for every pair of strings from the splitted value of every element
  // of [roads] ...
  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split(`-`))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }

  return graph;
}

// for demo
function Log() {
  const res = document.querySelector('#result');
  return (...args) => {
    args.forEach(arg =>
      res.appendChild(
        Object.assign(document.createElement(`div`), {
          innerHTML: `${arg}`,
          className: `logEntry`
        })
      ))
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/16px verdana, arial;
}

.logEntry {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

code {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: green;
  padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```